# PHP Syntax - Curly braces

Tags: php, syntax

So I have a simple class;

```
class Foo{
      public function bar(){
      // Do something
      }
}
$method = 'bar';
$object = new Foo;
```

Using

```
$object->{ $method }()
```

seems to work the same as writing

```
$object->$method()
```

Is there any difference between these and if not, why would you write it one way or the other?

Answer (score 1):

Difference between these styles become significant when instead of simple `$method` you use, for example, this:

```
class Baz {
    public function getMethodName()
    {
        return 'bar';
    }
}

class Foo{
      public function bar(){
        echo 'bar_run';
      }
}
$method = 'bar';
$object = new Foo;
$yao = new Baz();
// see this line:
$object->{$yao->getMethodName()}();   // outputs `bar_run`

// if you omit `{}`:
$object->$yao->getMethodName()();     // fatal error
```

So, `{}` should be used when it's not clear how to parse your code.

Of course, such codes like `$object->{$yao->getMethodName()}();` **must** be avoided. But still if there's some case in which it's not clearly understood how to execute an expression - better use `{}`.